# Number Theory Question - "Superfortunate" numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let us call a positive integer $n$ 'fortunate' if the sum of its digits is a multiple of 7, and 'superfortunate' if it is fortunate and if none of the numbers $n+1, n+2,\dots, n+12$ is fortunate. Find the smallest superfortunate number.

I tried finding a superfortunate number so I could create an upper bound and work back, but I couldn't find any superfortunate numbers. If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!!

Comment: Hint: If $n$ is a fortunate number, under what conditions is $n+7$ or $n+5$ also a fortunate number? Hence, what does that tell you about $n+12$?

Comment: Think about the digit sums of the 12 given consecutive numbers. What happens to the digit sum when you increment a number by 1? (Hint: it depends on how many 9s turn into 0s.)

Comment: "Fortunate" numbers are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A273159/b273159.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$993$ is the smallest superfortunate number.

You can obtain this by letting the digits of $n$ be $$... a 9 9 ... 9 b$$ where $a<9$ and there are, say, $k$ 9s. Then look at the results of adding 1,2,3 ... ,12.